# Can anyone identify this die with an 'a', a cheese wedge, a movie camera, a G-clef, a coffee cup and a moustache?

Tags: dice, identify-this-game-piece

[image: unknown die]

We have a random die, probably from a trivia game but we're not sure. Does anyone recognize it?

Comment: My first thought was Rory's Story Cubes but all images of that seem to be white dice.   There be other versions or clones.   I'd guess it some sort of story cube game but sadly can't find anything definitive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This dice is from [Hipster Dice](http://www.sjgames.com/dice/hipsterdice/).

[image]

[BGG:Hipster Dice](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/156350/hipster-dice)